# How to use reselect in react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect, react-boilerplate

I am using `react-boilerplate`

, and I am building a small kind of project so that I can understand the use of selectors.

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCQ0ZSr-a2o) which I enjoyed a lot and I believe I have a clear understanding of where I should use selectors.

So what the video says is that we should use selectors when we want to combine 2 or more states of redux and as a result have a combined state (always correct me if I am wrong please).

So given that definition, I have the following questions,

1. While using the boilerplate should I use selectors even if I don't have to combine 2 or more states?

For example, I have written the following selector

```
const selectCardRendererDomain = () => (state) => state.get('cardRenderer');

export {
  selectCardRendererDomain,
};
```

Which doesn't make much sense if you ask me, but I like to keep things uniform in my projects so that I can easily follow the same flow every time I need to visit some old code.

2. Are there any recipes that I can see how other, more experienced people are using selectors with the Boilerplate?
   I have already taken a look at the example of the boilerplate but I don't think that what I am looking for is there (again always correct me if I am wrong please).

Thanks in advance people

Answer (score 1):

Whether using a selector to access state properties or not, is a design decision and is up to you.

I personally prefer accessing state props through selectors only. The main benefits are:

- decoupling state shape from your components
- avoiding any pain if the state shape change in future
- testability

Using selectors (or memoized selectors) to compute/derive data from the state - instead - is currently a best practice in Redux-based applications.

Redux DOCS have a page dedicated to [Computing derived data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html). A very good read.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am gonna take a look at the article.